# Weird css/html gap when going to chrome mobile device view

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a weird gap that creates scroll on x axis when I switch from normal pc browser view to mobile view with F12 on google chrome. The gap exists on mobile view until I reload the page and then it's gone.
You can see it on the picture below.

```
<div id="search">
    </div>

    <div id="search-content">

        <div class="search-item"></div><br>     

</div>
```

CSS:

```
html{   
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header{
    color:white;    
    background: #0198E1;
    height: 65px;   
}

#header-text{
    margin: 0px;        
    height: 65px;   
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 17px;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#search{
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    background: #2a3849;
}

#search-content{
    background:#f4f4f4;
    width: 100%;    
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-top: 40px;  
}

.search-item{
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 9px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.31);
}

#content{   

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {

    .search-item{
        width: 95%;
        height: 180px;
    }

}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Is that a scrollbar space?

Comment: Any reason you have 
`html { width: 100%; }`? There really is no need for this since it is the default behavior and could be adding to problem.

Comment: @kannanD.S yes it is, what should I do about it. Should I put overflow-x:hidden? Yeah my bad with the html { width: 100%; } So the scrollbar is making this gap until page is reloaded.

Comment: In my jsfiddle I don't have this gap but a white space all around the body even in computer.

Comment: I equally dont have the gap try clearing your browser history

Comment: I've fixed it with overflow-x:hidden I think the gap was caused by as kannanD.S said scrollbar. The white space all around the body is gone when I use normalize.css

Comment: you can do one thing. if the page contains more details reduce the width of scroll bar. can i answer  it please accept it